# why i get error when i replace __init__ by other key word like(info)

Tags: python, class, init

```
class worker:
    def info(self,name,last,age,salary):
        self.name=name
        self.last=last
        self.age=age
        self.salary=salary
        self.email=name+last+'@'+'gmail.com'
emp1=worker('sujit','regmi',22,60000)
print(emp1.email)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in 
    emp1=worker('sujit','regmi',22,60000)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Comment: How is Python supposed to know you are intending to replace `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is the standard name for the constructor and you never call the constructor explicitly.
It is implicitly called when create the object.
Let's take your case.

```
class worker:
    def __init__(self,name,last,age,salary):
        self.name=name
        self.last=last
        self.age=age
        self.salary=salary
        self.email=name+last+'@'+'gmail.com'
emp1=worker('sujit','regmi',22,60000)
print(emp1.email)
```

Now, to initialize the class, you would be doing something like:

`emp1=worker('sujit','regmi',22,60000)`

And the class object will be created by calling the `__init__` implicitly.
But, when you change the name of the `__init__` function, Python doesn't know who to call to initialize the object.

That is why, it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with constructor.`__init__` is the keyword for using constructor in python:

```
class worker:
    def __init__(self,name,last,age,salary):
        self.name=name
        self.last=last
        self.age=age
        self.salary=salary
        self.email=name+last+'@'+'gmail.com'
emp1=worker('sujit','regmi',22,60000)
print(emp1.email)
```

Comment: explain properly, he knows it works with the constructor.

Comment: chill, take care the next time.